# call a function many times in parallel

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, fork

I want to call a function with different value of arg many times. To make the execution faster I want to call the function without considering its implementation.

Inside a loop i pass the arg to the function and call it now my program should not wait for the function to execute and loop again, instead it should not consider that the function has not completed for the first loop it should go ahead and call the function again and again till the loop ends.

how to use fork and threads to do this , which one will be faster and a skeleton of code will help ?
Lets say my function is void foo(arg1,arg2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an asynchronous implementation of the [proactor pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proactor_pattern)

Here's an example, using `boost::asio` and `boost::thread`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

// your function, with its arguments
void foo(int x, int y)
{
   cout << x << " * " << y << " = " << x * y << "\n";
}

int main()
{
   boost::asio::io_service svc;
   boost::asio::io_service::work w(svc);

   // create a thread to run the io_service proactor
   boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &svc));

   for(int z = 0; z < 32; ++z)
   {
      // bind the function to its arguments to 
      // be called in the context of the running
      // thread
      svc.post(boost::bind(&f, 2, z));
   }

   boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));

   svc.stop();
   thread.join();
}
```

The benefit here, is you can scale easily by calling `boost::asio::io_service::run` from a pool of threads if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a computationally intensive method then it's not a good idea to spawn a thread/process for each call (as a matter of fact, it's never a good idea!).

You can efficiently parallelize the for loop using openmp:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    int arg1 = ...
    int arg2 = ...
    foo(arg1, arg2);
}
```

This will create a number of threads according to the number of available CPU cores and then split the iterations among them. You can further tune the scheduling using the `schedule` clause.

Comment: The function calls a script which bring up/down daemons.The Script take lot of time to get completed so I want to instantiate the scripts and wait for them to complete

Answer (score 1):

Like Tudor has recommend, I would also use a `parallel_for` pattern algorithm from either Intel TBB or Microsoft PPL.

If you really want to spawn a need thread for every function, you can do it like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void foo(arg1, arg2) {
  //do stuff
}

int main() {

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  for(auto i = x; i != y; ++i)
    threads.emplace_back(foo, arg1, arg2);

  for(auto& i: threads)
    i.join();

}
```

Comment: How to implement this using fork ?

Answer (score 0):

In [github](https://github.com/tirimatangi/Lazy) there is a header-only library which can be used for calling a function asynchronously once for each element of a vector. If the function returns a value, it gives back the results in another vector. It avoids using std::future which has been criticized e.g. in [this](https://youtu.be/tF-Nz4aRWAM?t=780) CppCon presentation for being slow. Also exceptions can be caught normally.

Here is an example:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Lazy.h"

    template <class T1, class T2>
    double foo(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        return double(t1) + double(t2);
    }


    int main() {
        constexpr int maxThreads = 16; // 0 means as many threads as there are cores

        // Make an input vector
        std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> vecIn;
        for(int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
            vecIn.push_back({10 * i, 1.1 * (i+1)});

        try {
            auto vecOut = Lazy::runForAll<maxThreads>(vecIn,
                            [](auto in){ return foo(in.first, in.second); });

            for (auto i = 0; i < vecOut.size(); ++i)
                std::cout << "foo(" << vecIn[i].first
                          << ", " << vecIn[i].second
                          << ") = " << vecOut[i] << '\n';
        } catch (...)
        { // Deal with the exception here
        }
    }

    /* Output:
    foo(0, 1.1) = 1.1
    foo(10, 2.2) = 12.2
    foo(20, 3.3) = 23.3
    foo(30, 4.4) = 34.4
    foo(40, 5.5) = 45.5
    */
```