# How to create multiple sockets of each different port at server side application in C

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am implementing a client-server program in which server creates two sockets with different ports. The reason I need two ports is, one socket is to send X.txt file Data to the client and another socket is to send Y.txt file data to the client.

Eg: Client's which are connected to server's port1 receives X.txt file data and clients which are connected to server's port2 receives y.txt file data.

Can someone provide me with the working code in C Linux, in which 
a) How server creates two sockets with different ports
b) How server listens to these two sockets and accepts the incoming clients' requests.

Following is the approach I tried in server code:
. create two sockets(sock1, sock2)
. bind sock1 to IP address and port1
. bind sock2 to same IP address and port2
. call the listen method for sock1
. call the listen method for sock2

After this, I am not clear how to handle same time both socket's client requests? The following approach will not work because accept is blocking call:

```
while(1)
{
     int newsockfd1 = accept(sock1fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr1, &clilen1);
     int newsockfd2 = accept(sock2fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr2, &clilen2);

     //write X.txt data on newsockfd1
     // write Y.txt data on newsockfd2
}
```

Is there any approach like using select or poll? If it is possible through select() or poll() please provide me with the code in C for Linux.

Comment: `Can someone provide me the working code in C Linux,`...you made it off topic there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are no "gimme teh codez" site.

Comment: You need to 1. solve this with threads (e.g. [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)). And most important you need at least **try** to solve it yourself. Please read the tutorial and probably [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217719/call-a-function-many-times-in-parallel), take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and after that [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with what you have tried so far. The [information about pthreads on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+pthread) will be of much help, as well.

Comment: A single thread way would be to use non-blocking sockets and `select` to get information which of them can read. Look around to see how to set sockets non-blocking and how to use them with `select`. However, it is not a trivial implementation.

Comment: Thank you All.  The 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560336/listen-to-multiple-ports-from-one-server' has the solution, this is working to me.